# Find definition of type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have such DDL of tables from PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    id identifier NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('some_table_id_seq'),
    center_name common_name NULL,
    ...
)
```

Those `identifier` and `common_name` types are not standart PostgreSQL types. How to find their definitions?

Comment: Most likely it is [domains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) so in [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) use `\dD <name>` meta-command to get its properties, for example, `\dD+ identifier`

Comment: and `\dT+` for data types

Comment: Any chance to get this info from query?

Comment: "_`--echo-hidden`   Echo the actual queries generated by `\d` and other backslash commands. You can use this to study `psql`'s internal operations._"

Comment: @Abelisto thanks. The thing is I haven't access to host where database is running.

Comment: Sadly, while PostgreSQL has `pg_get_viewdef` and `pg_get_functiondef` it does not have `pg_get_tabledef`.

Comment: For domains: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fc2a6ab58026777a04c7ac1b828b1ba9

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid, NULL) AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(t.oid, 'pg_type') as "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
WHERE (t.typrelid = 0 OR (SELECT c.relkind = 'c' FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid))
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el WHERE el.oid = t.typelem AND el.typarray = t.oid)
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: got `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "LEFT"`

Comment: `SQL Error [25P02]: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
  ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "LEFT"`

Comment: I retrieved `schema`, `name` and `description` columns. But this `description` column is not the definition. It is just a verbouse description, given by creator of the type or domain. How to retrieve *defenition* with constraints and so on?